# calculate a total using SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 3 attributes:

```
Title          TotalNumberOfAuthors              TotalNumberOfPublishedAuthors
A                    3                                         1
B                    2                                         2
C                    4                                         2
D                    2                                         1
```

I am trying to create a query that Displays the Sum of **TotalNumberOfPublishedAuthors** and the sum of **TotalNumberOfNonPublishedAuthors** which is (TotalNumberofAuthors - TotalNumberOfPublishedAuthors)..

This is the query that I have generated, but doesn't display the results as expected:

```
SELECT SUM(Submission.TotalNumberOfPublishedAuthors),        
       (SUM(Submission.TotalNumberOfAuthors) - SUM(Submission.TotalNumberOfPublishedAuthors)) AS Number_of_Non_Published_Authors
FROM Submission INNER JOIN ((Faculty INNER JOIN School 
ON Faculty.FacultyID = School.[FacultyID]) INNER JOIN (Researcher INNER JOIN ResearcherSubmission 
ON Researcher.ResearcherID = ResearcherSubmission.ResearcherID) 
ON School.SchoolID = Researcher.SchoolID) 
ON Submission.SubmissionID = ResearcherSubmission.SubmissionID;
```

This is the result I am trying to get:

```
TotalNumberofPublishedAuthors                     TotalNumberofPublishedAuthors
         6                                                     5
```

Comment: Your question is confusing.  You say you have a table, then you show a query with multiple tables.  Can you set up a SQL Fiddle with some sample data?

Comment: Also it would help to show the value that is being returned, or is the SQL just not working?

Comment: Looking at the query you have used this should give you the result as you expect.  
`SUM(Submission.TotalNumberOfPublishedAuthors),        
 (SUM(Submission.TotalNumberOfAuthors) - SUM(Submission.TotalNumberOfPublishedAuthors))`
But as per you the result is different, what are you getting?

Comment: it looks like some problem with your join operation. check whether you are getting all row or not..... if you are getting all rows with your join, then definitely will get you correct result as you expected.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT <Column Names>
FROM <Table Name>
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL,SUM(<Column name>),null,sum(<RunningTotal or AnyTotal>)
FROM <Table Name>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really have columns in the table [Submission] called [TotalNumberOfPublishedAuthors] and [TotalNumberOfAuthors] as shown then there is no need to join any other tables. Just perform the sums as you already have them in the query but without further tables.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7a54b/2)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Submission
    ([Title] varchar(1), [TotalNumberOfAuthors] int, [TotalNumberOfPublishedAuthors] int)
;

INSERT INTO Submission
    ([Title], [TotalNumberOfAuthors], [TotalNumberOfPublishedAuthors])
VALUES
    ('A', 3, 1),
    ('B', 2, 2),
    ('C', 4, 2),
    ('D', 2, 1)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
      SUM(Submission.TotalNumberOfPublishedAuthors) AS TotalNumberOfPublishedAuthors
    , SUM(Submission.TotalNumberOfAuthors) 
    - SUM(Submission.TotalNumberOfPublishedAuthors) AS Number_of_Non_Published_Authors
FROM Submission
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7a54b/2/0)**:

```
| TotalNumberOfPublishedAuthors | Number_of_Non_Published_Authors |
|-------------------------------|---------------------------------|
|                             6 |                               5 |
```